# Xe–F bond length in xenon fluorides

Tags: bond

> The order of bond length of $\ce{Xe-F}$ in $\ce{XeF2}$, $\ce{XeF4}$, $\ce{XeF6}$ is?

My thoughts:

As hybridization of $\ce{Xe}$ in $\ce{XeF2}$ is $\ce{sp^3d}$, $\ce{XeF4}$ is $\ce{sp^3d^2}$, $\ce{XeF6}$ is $\ce{sp^3d^3}$.

%$\ce{s}$ decreases from $\ce{XeF2}$, $\ce{XeF4}$ to $\ce{XeF6}$, so bond length should increase, but my book says the opposite, i.e. $\ce{XeF2} > \ce{XeF4} > \ce{XeF6}$.

Comment: Downvoting for incorrect use of d orbital participation for main-group compounds.

Comment: @Jan I don't think a misconception in a question (and a misconception based on something which continues to be taught in general chemistry courses in the US) warrants a downvote.

Comment: Something seems fishy... Multiple sources say that the Xe-F bond is strongest in XeF2 and weakest in XeF6...

Comment: The explanation for the trend in bond strength of Xe-F in the xenon fluorides is the steric crowding about xenon, resulting in weaker bonds when there are more fluorine atoms packed around the central xenon atom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, your book is correct.
To rationalize it, throw away hydridization and electron exitation and work with concept of [three-center four-electron bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-center_four-electron_bond). The idea is that in $\ce{XeF2}$ the real structure is a mix of $\ce{F-Xe+...F^-}$ and $\ce{F^-...Xe+-F}$, so the bonding is half-covalent and half-ionic. By packing more fluorine around the xenone atom, we force xenone into state with higher effective atomic charge, so the ionic part of the bonding becomes stronger as $\ce{Xe^{3+}}$ pulls fluorine anions much stronger.

same logic applies to many other cases, in particular sulfur oxides and sulfur fluorides.

For context, I quote experimental bond lengths from [paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja0423116). Note, the paper itself quotes the values from other sources with slightly different values from different sources.

XeF2 ... 1.977

XeF4 ... 1.94

XeF6 ... 1.94 & 1.850 (two bond types)

Comment: Your resonance structure doesn't seem correct. In your structure, there is a negative formal charge on fluorine and the Xe-F portion is neutral, giving an overall negative charge to the molecule. However, the XeF2 molecule is neutral.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because higher number of fluorine atoms induce a higher positive oxidation state on Xe which causes the Xe atom to shrink in size resulting in a smaller bond length.

XeF2 has Xe in +2 oxidation state while XeF6 has it in +6 oxidation state

[link](https://edu.rsc.org/download?ac=135029)