How does Xe rearrange its electrons for hybridization in XeF6
Please include how Xe moves its electrons in d block with diagrams if possible.
I have already tried drawing the movement of electrons but i dont get where it would send its electrons as there is a large energy gap between 3d and 4d

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50187/what-is-hybridisation-of-xef6-in-solid-state/50189 ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/85219/xe-f-bond-length-in-xenon-fluorides
